How to locate the automation's "Emulator Extended Control Xpath"
After using webdriver io for a while, I want to automate some tasks. For example, I want to use the Touch sensor in the Android emulator, but I can't seem to find the xpath or send keys for that. I've tried a lot of different things, but it would be better if someone could tell me where to look to find the components that need to interact.
